# How to send a parallel request to more than one server in Android?

Tags: android

My application regarding as showing list of MP3 songs listview from server on click of particular listview song am background download that song into sd card up to that task done successfully but client need when user click on more MP3 songs at the same time from listview then that song also download parallel in background but my code work only last select song is downloading

Please provide code or logic.

Comment: [**What have you tried?**](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried)

Answer (score 0):

Abstract it out. Write a class to queue downloads then have that class initiate a new download as each file completes. That way you can handle things such as duplicate onItemSelected calls. I'm not sure why you added the multidimensional array tag, but it would be easier to understand what your goal was if you attached code to your question.